# Great Expectations: expect_values_to_match_regex rule gives out error for all regex

Tags: great-expectations

NOTE: Running on **Snowflake**

I actually need the regex to check for SSN. The one I'm using is -
**Regex used:** '^(?!666|000|9\\d{2})\\d{3}-(?!00)\\d{2}-(?!0{4})\\d{4}$'
**Error message**:
Invalid regular expression: '^(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0{4})\d{4}$', no argument for repetition operator: ?\n[SQL: SELECT sum(CASE WHEN (ssn IS NOT NULL AND NOT (ssn RLIKE %(param_1)s)) THEN %(param_2)s ELSE %(param_3)s END) AS "column_values.match_regex.unexpected_count", sum(CASE WHEN (ssn IS NULL) THEN %(param_4)s ELSE %(param_5)s END) AS "column_values.nonnull.unexpected_count" \nFROM ge_temp_4b471582]\n[parameters: {'param_1': '^(?!666|000|9\\d{2})\\d{3}-(?!00)\\d{2}-(?!0{4})\\d{4}$', 'param_2': 1, 'param_3': 0, 'param_4': 1, 'param_5': 0}]

**Rule used:**
{"expectation_type": "expect_column_values_to_match_regex", "kwargs": {"column": "ssn", "regex": "^(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0{4})\d{4}$"}, "meta": {}}

A couple months ago, when I ran this, it was running perfectly. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Or is it a problem from Great Expectation's side?

So, I figured there must be a problem with the regex. But, using a basic regex like the one mentioned below, I'm getting a similar error.
**regex used**: '[Aa-Zz]'
**Error message**:
Invalid regular expression: '[Aa-Zz]', invalid character class range: a-Z\n[SQL: SELECT first AS unexpected_values \nFROM ge_temp_de90d2b5 \nWHERE first IS NOT NULL AND NOT (first RLIKE %(param_1)s)\n LIMIT %(param_2)s]\n[parameters: {'param_1': '[Aa-Zz]', 'param_2': 20}]\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)\n"/n%22),

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can omit `^` and `$` for Snowflake because it adds it automatically.
2. Snowflake doesn't support negative lookahead operators https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007ENLKsSAP/expanded-support-for-regular-expressions-regex
3. You can make another expectation using expect_column_values_to_not_match_regex for the negative cases
4. [Aa-Zz] is not a valid regular expression. I think you wanted [A-Za-z]